# bash loop restart a program

Tags: bash

I'd like to close and restart a program (amule) every 4 minutes as loop (until myself will decide to close).
I tried this code

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( ; ; ))
do
amule
sleep 240;
wmctrl -c aMule;
done
```

but it doesn't work (even after disabling confirm on exit).

EDIT
1) I **mean** that this script should close amule after 240 seconds (sorry 180 was a mistake), and then (immediatly) re-open it. And, afterwards, after 240 re-close and re-open and so on.
2) yes the **name** is correct and when I try to run that line /(wmctrl -c aMule;) from konsole, it works

EDIT
I tried to do so:
1) creating a new script:

```
wmctrl -c aMule
sleep 10
amule
```

2) adding ths script to crontab (run every 6 minutes)

But the command "wmctrl -c aMule", which **works from terminal**, doesn't work from (such) a script.
I don't understand why...

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Please [edit] your question and describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens. BTW: 180 seconds are 3 minutes.

Comment: Use `while :; do ... done`.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve. We can see you're using `wmctrl` which per the manpage closes a named window with the `-c` option. How are you determining the window name? Have you confirmed it's correct? Does `wmctrl -c aMule` work _outside_ the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the updates! The user instance that launches your script via `cron` doesn't own the display, so it doesn't know about any windows by any name. You'll either need to 1) run your script in a terminal, or 2) (I don't recommend this unless you have insomnia) read up on `xauth` for how to share Xauthority keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`amule` works in the foreground. Your script never gets to `sleep 240`. Run `amule` in the background, so the script can continue.

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
   amule &     # run in background
   sleep 240
   killall amule
      # or   wmctrl -c aMule
   wait         # in case amule needs time to close
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
watch -n 240 'amule;wmctrl -c aMule'
```

Comment: thank you, but your code didn't work

Comment: if command 'amule' takes more time , then it won't

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing `wmctrl -c aMule;` with `killlall amule` or `pkill amule`, depending upon which of `killall` or `pkill` you have installed.  You might need to add the option `-KILL` before `amule` if amule ignores the TERM signal.